# Jquery Select an attribute with slashs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, escaping

I'm trying to select an object with JQuery filtering by a value of an attribute that is a unique filename. I can't escape from slashes when the selector is made with a var. I lost 2 hours trying with multiple combinations but I think I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for the light

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="CLKPMTable_2"><tbody><tr class="click-row" valuetype="PM" filename="\\server\folder\file1" paymentmethodid="1"><td class="col-md-1"><img width="24" height="24" src="/Content/img/123.png" id="PMURLIMG_"></td><td class="col-md-10" id="PM_FILENAME_">BO OCT</td><td class="col-md-1 text-right"><img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/img/notyet.png" id="PM_STATUS_"></td></tr><tr class="click-row" valuetype="PM" filename="\\server\folder\file2" paymentmethodid="2"><td class="col-md-1"><img width="24" height="24" src="/Content/img/visa.png" id="PMURLIMG_"></td><td class="col-md-10" id="PM_FILENAME_">O SEP</td><td class="col-md-1 text-right"><img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/img/notyet.png" id="PM_STATUS_"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

My Javascript:

```
var filename = "\\server\folder\file1";
var selec = $('tr[valueType="PM"][filename="'+filename+'"]');
alert(selec.attr("paymentmethodid"));
```

Didn't work neither with:

```
var filenamescaped = filename.replace('\\','\\\\')
var selec = $('tr[valueType="PM"][filename="'+filenamescaped+'"]');
```

Also didn't work neither with (from: [Jquery official doc to escape chars used in css](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)):

```
function jq( myid ) {
 return myid.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=)/g, "\\$1" );
}

 var filename = "\\server\folder\file1";
  var filenamescaped = jq(filename);
```

My fiddler to make some test:
[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rab9vy3w/)

Comment: didn't work with replace double escape slash

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `var filename = "\\\\server\\folder\\file1"; alert("Test: "+filename);` This escapes that backslashes.

Comment: Hi @Feathercrown and thanks. Tried with a replace and didnt work neither.
Check my update.

Comment: Try using `.replace("/","//")` instead of `.replace("//","////")`; the second one won't replace the single slashes.

Comment: The thing is that the slashs are "\" and I've the scape them from the "replace" command itself

Comment: Oh yeah, whoops. I don't know then... what IS it giving you?

Comment: the filenamescaped returns ok, but the attribute is undefined. With a value without slashes, it works fine, so I assume the problem are the slashes. I can't hardcore the filename, actually is a variable getting from json. Just hardcoded for the example.

Comment: So what's happening is the `\f`s are turning into form feed characters; even if they weren't f's, the backslashes would still be "used up" before the replace happens, since they are evaluated in the string declaration, not where it's used. As for a solution, I still have no idea....

Comment: The problem is that the backslashes are already gone by the time you have the chance to run a replace command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value's backslash needs, in this case, to be doubled twice for it to work as a valid selector

```js
var filename = "\\\\\\\\server\\\\folder\\\\file1";
var selec = document.querySelector('tr[valueType="PM"][filename="'+filename+'"]');
alert(selec.getAttribute("paymentmethodid"));
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed" id="CLKPMTable_2"><tbody><tr class="click-row" valuetype="PM" filename="\\server\folder\file1" paymentmethodid="1"><td class="col-md-1"><img width="24" height="24" src="/Content/img/123.png" id="PMURLIMG_"></td><td class="col-md-10" id="PM_FILENAME_">BO OCT</td><td class="col-md-1 text-right"><img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/img/notyet.png" id="PM_STATUS_"></td></tr><tr class="click-row" valuetype="PM" filename="\\server\folder\file2" paymentmethodid="2"><td class="col-md-1"><img width="24" height="24" src="/Content/img/visa.png" id="PMURLIMG_"></td><td class="col-md-10" id="PM_FILENAME_">O SEP</td><td class="col-md-1 text-right"><img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/img/notyet.png" id="PM_STATUS_"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**Updated**

In your particular case the `filename` value need to be already escaped for the replace to work, as in `var filename="\\\\server\\folder\\file1"`

*Do note the global switch in the replace command so it replace all occurrences*

```js
var filename = "\\\\server\\folder\\file1";
var filenamescaped = filename.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\\\\\');
var selec = $('tr[valueType="PM"][filename="'+filenamescaped+'"]');
alert(selec.attr("paymentmethodid"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed" id="CLKPMTable_2"><tbody><tr class="click-row" valuetype="PM" filename="\\\\server\\folder\\file1" paymentmethodid="1"><td class="col-md-1"><img width="24" height="24" src="/Content/img/123.png" id="PMURLIMG_"></td><td class="col-md-10" id="PM_FILENAME_">BO OCT</td><td class="col-md-1 text-right"><img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/img/notyet.png" id="PM_STATUS_"></td></tr><tr class="click-row" valuetype="PM" filename="\\server\folder\file2" paymentmethodid="2"><td class="col-md-1"><img width="24" height="24" src="/Content/img/visa.png" id="PMURLIMG_"></td><td class="col-md-10" id="PM_FILENAME_">O SEP</td><td class="col-md-1 text-right"><img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/img/notyet.png" id="PM_STATUS_"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Won't work, he can't change the variable directly, only the replace command, by which time the backslashes are already gone. Although I don't think this is even solvable at this point in the code; it would have to be "fixed" earlier, so it isn't your fault.

Comment: Thanks. I get to this solution from this: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14417 Actually I'm trying to hit my head to insert that logic into a "replace", as @Feathercrown said I can't hardcoded the logic and replace seems doesn't work in that way (\\ by \\\\\\\\)

Comment: Tried several ways @LGSon and I can't replace slash with four slashes with replace :S

Comment: @LeandroTupone I am testing too, will give it a go a few more tests

Comment: @LeandroTupone Updated my answer ... might or might not help but shows what's needed

Comment: da*n, this is hard. I tried on that way but didn't work

Comment: @Feathercrown What I did work, though the OP can't use it 'cause the slashes are, as you said, gone ... so does my answer add value or should I delete it?

Comment: I've never known when a good time to delete an answer is... I'd keep it, but add on a "disclaimer" or sorts.

Comment: I think my problem now is trying to get the filename with the slashs already. For instance, how to get from filename to your filename without hardcoding? Tried with split and join, and using escape() function but didn't work. I can't believe this is so hard :S

Comment: @LeandroTupone Where does the _filename_ value come from in the first place?

Comment: From an array of objects, objects with that property that i pushed selecting a group of rows and getting the filename property. I think I've to create a self index for this and another unique value.

Comment: The thing is that for this case, i need to send to the server this unique id

Comment: @LeandroTupone Can you replace on that array object's value? ... as with my 2:nd sample's replace command

Comment: Actually I used a composed unique code to identify the html element, but thanks anyway.